# create workflow in share point designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a library and have a list 
I want that when user add item to library then a item create in list.
so i design workflow in share point designer but workflow act for user that have full permission and for other use that have no permission for list ,after user add document to library ,workflow does not work.
can run workflow for all user?

Answer (score 1):

Workflow runs as per "Initiator" permissions indeed. In SharePoint 2010 Designer there is a new Activity which allows you to Impersonate as the person Designing the Workflow, which actually will allow you to design it with the account that should have enough permissions.
See here for how it works:
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/31/impersonation-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow/

Do consider however making only a small part of your workflow running under Impersonation, to avoid other side issues, such as Modified/Created properties being stored with other values.